# Making sense of maptitude's geocoding results

Tags: geocoding, maptitude

I'm using maptitude to populate latitude and longitude from a dataset for further mapping.

However, after geocoding on address, i'm being given lat/lons that make no sense. See the examples below

```
Lat         Lon
-72576271   42256531
-73203079   42712224
-70822976   42587150
-71089458   42339990
-71127491   42382567
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I can't seem to change the format to anything I recognize. When I take these out of maptitude the rest of my software can't make sense of it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the data in or near Massachusetts? If so, for some reason they're swapping the latitude and longitude and both values should be divided by 10e6. That is, lon:-72.576271 lat: 42.256531

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mkennedy suggests, Maptitude reports the coordinates in millionths. They are actually stored (and reported) as long integers - presumably for speed.

To convert to decimal degrees (in Maptitude's current coordinate system) then multiply by 1.0e-6.

Similarly when creating a Maptitude Coord object, multiple your coordinates by 1.0e6 and convert to long integer.